# Examples that lead to data loss in YugabyteDB xCluster replication

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Looking at the docs, https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/explore/multi-region-deployments/ - over here it says that the xCluster pattern leads to some data loss (RPO). What are the specific scenarios when data loss can occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenarios where XCluster would have data loss are in write-write configurations. Two options are [1] conflict resolution where last writer wins and [2] Read-Modify-Write when reading data that has been modified by the other cluster but is part of outstanding replication transactions in the asynchronous lag.